# Only deprecated segue available

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a strange problem. I have an old project on which I am working on since October and there is no adaptive segue option for that project. Anyway when I create a new project, I have those options.

Here is what I see :

[image]

[image]

Did anyone ever experienced that ?

Comment: The adaptive segues are available when you are using Size Classes.  This can be toggled in the File Inspector.

Comment: Thank you so much !